# Objective C - NSMutableArrays - For each

Tags: objective-c

I would like to know if there is a better way to set each objects in a NSMutableArray a property value ?

```
//player.h
@interface Player : NSObject
@property BOOL isEliminated;

//test.h
@property NSMutableArray *players;

//test.m
for(Player *p in self.players)
{
    p.isEliminated = NO;
}
```

I am pretty new to xCode and I have a C# background. I know C# & Linq can provide a non-loop solution.. I would like to know if this is also possible with Objective C

I search here and there... All I could found is a way to get objects from array where property X equals somevalue..

Comment: @John, I know I can't... The NSMutableArray is filled with NSObject (Player)....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Key-Value Coding:

```
[self.players setValue:@NO forKey:@"isEliminated];
```

sets the property on each element of the array.

Note that even though the property is a (scalar) `BOOL`, you have to use the Objective-C
number object `@NO` here. It is automatically "translated" to `NO` when setting the
property.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you *can* create one loopless solution with blocks and `NSArray`s `- (void)enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))block` message. Something like:

```
[self.players enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Player *p, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    p.isEliminated = NO;
}];
```

However, this is hardly more readable. Using a loop for this type of work is, in my opinion, fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use makeObjectsPerformSelector: method on NSMutableArray to set change value of all object in NSMutableArray:

```
[self.players makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setIsEliminated:) withObject:@NO];
```